# Mis tablas se comparten en ORACLE

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Lo que sucede es que al crear una nueva base tiene las mimas tablas que una base de datos ya creadas, es decir que comparten las mismas tablas.

En este imagen se puede observa la tabla Alumnos, lo raro sucede que jamas cree una tabla Alumnos ahí sino mas bien en otra base de datos que es BD2

[image: En este imagen se puede observa la tabla Alumnos, lo raro sucede que jamas cree una tabla Alumnos ahí sino mas bien en otra base de datos que es BD2]

[image: En esta si la cree]

Lo que sucede es que si modifico una la otra también se modifica. Hay alguna solución para esto.

Comment: Esto no puede pasar jamás, a menos que hayas reutilizado los data-files de una base de datos en otra.

Answer (score 0):

En la imagen que muestras se ve el nombre que le pusiste a la conexión en sqldeveloper, sin embargo, la conexión no significa que el usuario sea diferente.
Te dejo una captura para que revises que ambas conexiones tienen diferente usuario.

Otra cosa que podrías validar es si te estás conectando por TNS, revisar que el nombre de la instancia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]